# void in TypeScript. Why do I get the result from the console.log?

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

```
let foo: void;
foo = 2;
```

I didn't get, explain to me please. When we type void with LET - ok, I got.

But, when we type for example here:

```
function test(message): void {
  console.log(message);
}

test("hi");
```

anyway I will get "hi". Why ?

Comment: i don't see result, i just see console logging

Comment: I am trying really hard to understand your question but it is not clicking for me. What are you asking exactly? Are you unsure why you get output in the console.log? Or do you think you should not be allowed to call the function `log`?

Comment: to make it quick: `function test(message: string): void` -> `string` is the TYPE of a property/variable (your 1st example - on top); `void` is the TYPE returned by a function (your 2nd example)

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it a little. So yes, why am I getting the result from function?

Comment: `why am I getting the result from function` ← You are *not* getting the result from the function. The side effect of the function is that a message is sent to console.log which prints it out to the console but the function itself does not return anything. `console.log` is not the same thing as a return value from a function.

Comment: Hi @SweetCaramel, first of all, hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Let me explain it again, what happened here. And because you already understood the "void" typing of a variable, I'll go on and only explain your function example. There you defined a function with the name "test" and defined, that this function can be called with the parameter "message" which is typed "any". The type "any" comes from not having put an explicit type there. The function "test" would return a value of type "void". Which basically means, you won't return anything. You are only printing the value on the console.

Comment: If you would want to get the return value from the function, you'd use a type like "string" or "number" or any class. If you don't define a return type, like this: function test(message) { ... } then you could return anything, because that would mean "any".

Comment: Also, if you want to get the return value of that function you'd do something like this: const returnedValue = test("hi"); but then you'd need a return type other than "void".

Comment: Thanks guys for the explanations. One more thing, can you give me an example. What value should I type instead of "console.log"?(the void is still there). Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last type on function is used to define type of its return.

And you might asking, why it does work?

```js
function test(msg: string): void {
  console.log(msg);
}
```

Because it doesn't return anything.

```js
let myVar: void = test("hello!");
console.log(myVar);
```

When you try it, myVar will return `undefined`, because the function itself return nothing. It is the same as [this Typescript example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#void).

```js
let unusable: void = undefined;
```

---

So what return means? Return is data that returned from function. Example:

```js
function idk(): string {
   return "Hello World!";
}
```

Then, when I execute it, it does return string.

```js
let myVar: string = idk();
console.log(myVar);
```

Have a look to this [return documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) by MDN.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. So, console.log and return do different things?
Console.log - only shows us information about the argument.
Return - gives us value.
Right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I forgot to mention about the use of console.log. But that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused trying to understand

> I didn't get, explain to me please. When we type void with LET - ok, I got

but if I'm parsing it correctly in my head, the second half of the question shows void as the return type of a function (in that case, nothing) whereas the first half of the question shows a void variable, to which Typescript only allows `null` or `undefined` as assignments.

Second half works because the function doesn't try to return anything. It does not accept "void" as a parameter. `message` type is untyped, so effectively any object would be allowed in.